# How to implement a policy for purging documents from Kuali Financial System (KFS)?

Tags: archiving, purge, kuali

Is it possible to logically remove documents based on a date?

Currently the Kuali Financial System does not have a built in mechanism for purging or archiving documents.  They all remain in their respective tables once created, including attachments in either the file system or in the database.

If any institutions implemented this, how was it implemented from a technical and policy standpoint?

If there are pros and cons with your specific technical/policy approach please include them in your response.  One thing that I know differs from institution to institution is whether attachments are stored in file system or database, so if your solution assumes one or the other please include that.

Comment: Stack Overflow is not a forum; we do not provide "information or discussion" here.  We answer specific questions.  If you really just want to know "How do I purge documents from KFS?", consider making that your question title and editing out the request for discussion.

Comment: Thanks @JeffreyBosboom for helping me clearly write the question, I appreciate it!